# Communication between two java application working fine with JBoss 7.0 but not working in Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I have two java application Portal and Report (Calling Report from Portal) which work fine with JBoss server. Now I am trying it to migrate from JBoss 7.0 to Tomcat 8.5 and I am getting below error.

```
classcastexception: org.apache.catalina.util.parametermap cannot be cast to java.util.hashmap

Code,
  ReportVO reportVO = new ReportVO();
  reportVO.setAttributes((HashMap<String, String[]>)request.getParameterMap());
```

**Note**: Portal is working fine in tomcat but when I am trying to generate any report by calling the Report application from Portal then I am getting above error.

Do I need to do any server side configuration?

Comment: The return type of `getParameterMap()` is just `Map<String, String[]>`

Comment: @GyroGearless HashMap<String, String[]> works fine in JBoss server.

Answer (score 0):

It is unable to convert to the expected class. I assume it is because of Jars priority.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have many jar in project which one need to check?